# SQL server connection to ASP.NET Core website

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, database-connection, connection-string

I making a ASP.NET CORE 2.1 website. The database in Visual studio works fine, but when i deployed to the IIS which on another computer, the database not work.
In log, the error:

```
fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query[10100]
  An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query for context type 'WebApplication3.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.
  System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported: 'id'.
.................
```

The connectionstring in the web.config:

```
 "ConnectionStrings": {
"DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Database=XXXX;Trusted_Connection=True;ID=XXXXXXX;pwd=XXXXXXXXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=true "
```

},

I read lot of articles for this, but i cant add any plus tags for the connection string, wil be error, the connection string is bad? 
When i run the project the in Visual Studio i can use database and i see the database in the SQL Server Managment Studio.

For the database i use the "stock database" when  created a the project in visual studio.
Because i use Entity Framework i need another format connection string?
[Stock Databse](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r6B46.png)

Comment: `Trusted_Connection=True;ID=XXXXXXX;pwd=XXXXXXXXX;` doesn't make sense. If you are using a trusted connection you don't pass the username and password (and conversely if you aren't using a trusted connection you do pass the values).

Comment: Good to know, but if use Trusted_Connection with true, no password or Trusted_connection false with userid, and password, no connect to databse, the error message:
 `An exception occurred in the database while iterating the results of a query for context type 'WebApplication3.Data.ApplicationDbContext'.
      System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot open database "XXX" requested by the login. The login failed.
      Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\XXXv11'.`

Comment: Sounds like the user/login `IIS APPPOOL\XXXv11` doesn't have access to the database then, @bobo. You need to check the user/login's permissions on your SQL Server and provide it with the relevant/correct permissions (we don't know what those are, we know nothing about your system, or what it does).

Comment: @Lamu ,Thanks the answer for login issue.I added the permission and login issue is gone, now i got only the same error as in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oh my jesus... I figured out the answer.. Just one f*... word... In connenction strig DONT USE *database*, the correct word is **Initial Catalog** and maybe use user id instead of id.
Correct string:

```
    "DefaultConnection": "Server=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=XXX;Trusted_Connection=False;user id=XXX;pwd=XXX;MultipleActiveResultSets=true "
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on my research if the server have morethan one databases .net core suffers to identify if the dabtase is mentioned in connection string.

This is not a problem if you use .Net framework, instead of .Net Core.

Comment: Fortunately, you can mix the things.